# Sqlite - Joining two related tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables which are related in the following way:

Table A is a list of college courses and instances of that course, for example the "course" Maths runs on a Tuesday and a Thursday and therefore has two "course_periods".  This is described in the following table:

**Table A**

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Maths | course |
| 0002 | Maths (Thursday) | course_period |
| 0003 | Maths (Tuesday) | course_period |

There is another table which connects all the "course periods" to their parent "courses" and looks like this:

**Table B**

| id | source | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0001 | 0002 |
| 0002 | 0001 | 0003 |

I would like to produce the last below table which joins the two tables **A & B** in the following way:

| destination_id | name_course_period | source_id | name_course |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | Maths(Thursday) | 0001 | Maths |
| 0003 | Maths(Tuesday) | 0001 | Maths |

I simply can't find the correct join statement to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You must join `TableB` to 2 copies of `TableA`:

```
SELECT b.destination destination_id,
       a2.name name_course_period,
       b.source source_id,
       a1.name name_course
FROM TableB b 
INNER JOIN TableA a1 ON a1.id = b.source
INNER JOIN TableA a2 ON a2.id = b.destination;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1e1b7a4db7be0ee4346b732c5f74ee75).

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your tables as cte, you need to start with table `a` as your base table.  Join this table to `b`.

You then need to join *back to* `a` to get the `name` of the destination.

```
with a as (
select '0001' id, 'Maths' name, 'course' type
union all select '0002', 'Maths (Thursday)','course_period' 
union all select '0003', 'Maths (Tuesday)', 'course_period'
)
, b as (
select '0001' id, '0001' source, '0002' destination
union all select '0002', '0001', '0003'
)
select 
b.id as destination_id
, ref.name as name_course_period
, b.source as source_id
, a.name as name_course
from a 
inner join b on b.source = a.id 
inner join a ref on ref.id = b.destination  --join back to a for name
```

Comment: What is the point of `where a.type = 'course'`? The query is already filtered by the ON clause: `on b.source = a.id` and since `b.source` refers to a `'course'` type (by design) it will not make a difference.